# PhpStorm $SELECTION$ in live template does not work

Tags: phpstorm, live-templates

I watched this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8LXJfYvq8z8

and tried to make a live template for try catch block.

```
try {
    $SELECTION$
} catch ($TYPE$ $$$VARIABLENAME$) {
    $END$
}
```

Now I select a code which I want to be surrounded and choose this template. I get:

```
try {

        } catch ( $) {

            }
```

No selected code in try block. What is wrong? Version is 2016.3.2, build on December 20, 2016

Is it a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: *"Now I select a code which I want to be surrounded and choose this template."* How do you choose a template? It works fine here. You must be doing something wrong. Please illustrate it with screenshot or screencast.

Comment: @LazyOne - found what was wrong, wrote answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found an answer while watching another video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h5p90FvJo0Y

It turns out that I have to not only select text, but also use different shortcut.

By default it is ctrl + alt + J. I was using ctrl + J so thats why it did not work.

Comment: thank you, this helped me, dont know why they did it this way